# How to display unique data with MySQL which is inserted by same and multiple users?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance

[image]

Consider this table with records for with item_id = 7777

I want sum items in this way.

- For example first two records should be considered as one.(both are
  inserted by guest_id =1111). We will take the last one which is id => 99, "down" value is greater than "up" value. so increment "down" by 1.
- From 101 to 103, it should take last one (which is 103) and in last we have up = 0, down =12 (so increment "down" by 1 because in last record "down" value is greater than up)
- Last two records are unique with unique guest_id and both have up => 1, so "up" will be incremented twice.

Result (count_up = 2, count_down = 2)

I wrote the query, but i am not sure if it is best and fast.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT IF(up > 0, USER, NULL)) AS voters_up,   COUNT(DISTINCT IF(down > 0, USER, NULL)) AS voters_down
FROM `items_votes` AS itemA
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT IF(guest_id IS NULL, user_id, guest_id) AS USER, MAX(id) AS id, item_id
    FROM items_votes
    WHERE item_id = 7777
   GROUP BY guest_id,user_id) AS itemB ON itemA.id = itemB.id
WHERE itemA.item_id = 7777
```

This above query and returns as what I expect.

[image]

But this query returns unique sum for only one item. Query doesn't work if I remove "where condition" for item_id.

How to do the same for all item_id?

Please help me with query for returning unique above sum for all items.

Comment: Your query is reasonable if it really works.

Comment: but it works for one item_id i want to do for all items_id if i remove item_id condition. then it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If your query works, then use it.  I think this version is simpler:

```
SELECT SUM(up > down) as up_votes,
       SUM(down > up) as down_votes
FROM items_votes iv JOIN
     (SELECT COALESCE(iv2.guest_id, iv2.user_id) as gu_id, MAX(id) as max_id
      FROM items_votes iv2
      WHERE iv2.item_id = 7777
      GROUP BY COALESCE(iv2.guest_id, iv2.user_id)
     ) iv2
     ON iv.id = iv2.max_id;
```

Notes:

- This aggregates by the guest/user id to get the most recent entry (based on id).
- This is then *inner* joined back to the original data.
- There is now one row per guest/user, so `count(distinct)` is not needed.

EDIT:

For all ids:

```
SELECT item_id, SUM(up > down) as up_votes,
       SUM(down > up) as down_votes
FROM items_votes iv JOIN
     (SELECT item_id, COALESCE(iv2.guest_id, iv2.user_id) as gu_id,
             MAX(id) as max_id
      FROM items_votes iv2
      WHERE iv2.item_id = 7777
      GROUP BY item_id, COALESCE(iv2.guest_id, iv2.user_id)
     ) iv2
     ON iv.id = iv2.max_id
GROUP BY item_id;
```

Comment: thanks but as i wrote in description, How to do without  "item_id=7777". i want to do same for all items.